# How to get better control of printer output from web applications?

Tags: web-applications, printing

We've been developing web-based systems for a while now. Our clients are often used to desktop applications, and we are generally upgrading their systems to a web-based version. This has many benefits for them, but often we encounter one drawback: printing output. The systems we develop often generate some document which needs to be printed, like:

- Invoices
- Receipts
- Order information
- Instruction Sheets
- Checks

Many of these documents have a pre-established format, and should appear in the same or very similar fashion. However, this is often a pain. Problems encountered include:

- Browsers often printing headers and footer (page numbering, date, etc), which only the client can control.
- Certain printing styles are poorly supported (eg `page-break-inside`), which makes it hard to control where information is cut off.
- Margins and paper size can not be controlled by the application, and require that the user changes this every time a specific document needs to be printed.
- In my experience, changing paper size and orientation is even a pain when doing this as a common user. For some reason, browsers do not instantly show changes to paper size, and for many, many clients I've had to instruct them to change the paper size, then click on "Change paper orientation" twice (from horizontal to vertical and back to horizontal), in order to properly preview the new paper size.
- A webbrowser can not (understandably) automatically print a document. So to directly print a receipt off a web-application, I've had to install a local webserver on every client and call a local web-page, which in return uses a programming language (in my case PHP) that runs a script to locally print. Quite a roundabout.

All in all, generating very specifically designed documents and printing them in that same way has proven to take way too much time and effort, with poor results. My question is: are people who have also dealt with this problem, and found a better solution? My current solution is to invest a whole bunch of time, try to educate the users, document all steps users need to take to get the preferred print output, and repeat and repeat as personnel, computers, and printers change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the best way is old school.  We have to print thousands of pages a night to a dot matrix pre-printed form printer.  So we have found it is best to go back to using a print control and literally send everything to the screen as though it was one character fixed font size like courier.

so we   then have print_field($xxxx,10,"right");  The function will pad with spaces or truncate if longer then 10 and put that to the screen.  The right is a function that right pads left pads or centers.  Then you can  do print_spaces(2),print_line(1) etc...

Then everything is exact positioned.  Again it seems like a pain but if you develop a few functions for it once then it actually makes custom forms easier.  We have a wrapper program that does all the data calls.  And made a xxx_header.php, xxx_detail, xxx_footer, page that gets included as needed and is normally just a few lines of the print_xxx functions called in a loop.

If you do this remember to keep a $ln_cnt line count.  Because at the end of your detail you will have to take $blank_lines_needed=$page_length-$ln_cnt  and do a loop for print_line($blank_lines_needed);

Again it seems like a lot but if you do it this way it will work every time without fail.  We print more dot matrix forms via web daily probably then most companies.  Across the US we are printing probably 60,000 pages nightly of pre-printed forms via the web. Hope this helps.

We then have a job that uses CURL and a pdf utlity that we can render an exact copy to pdf electronically.  So we can email invoices if the customer so choose. But they print the exact size if we send them to a dot matrix so they always look the same.

Answer (score 0):

script to dynamic images or scripted PDF generation fixes some of the headaches. then on printing they can just scale to fit page